# Scala How to Define a Method in a Trait to Return a Subclass Generically

Tags: scala

Given a very simplified model of what I am trying to implement:

```
sealed trait Data
case class CustomerData(values: List[String])
case class EmployeeData(values: List[String])
```

I want to define a method on the trait that requires each of the case classes to define a method that returns a new instance with an additional string. The following doesn't seem to work and it perplexes me but also I want the T to not just me any kind of data but the actual type of the subclass:

```
sealed trait Data {
  def withNewValue[T <: Data](v : String) : T
}
```

The subclass then should look like:

```
case class CustomerData(values: List[String]) {
  override def withNewValue[CustomerData](v : String) : CustomerData = CustomerData(v :: values)
}
```

But this doesnt compile nor does it restrict the override to require that the type be CustomerData rather than EmployeeData permitting someone to do something silly like:

```
case class CustomerData(values: List[String]) {
  override def withNew[EmployeeData](v : String) : EmployeeData = EmployeeData(v :: values)
}
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish what I am going for?

Comment: I believe 'self types' are the solution here but I'm not super familiar with them myself

Comment: Note that `override def withNewValue[CustomerData](v : String) : CustomerData = CustomerData(v :: values)` is the same as `override def withNewValue[A](v : String) : A = A(v :: values)`. `CustomerData` here is just a parameter name unrelated to `case class CustomerData`.

Answer (score 5):

One way to do that is to parameterize the trait itself, not the method:

```
sealed trait Data[T <: Data[T]] {
  def withNewValue(v : String): T
}

case class CustomerData(values: List[String]) extends Data[CustomerData] {
  def withNewValue(v : String): CustomerData = CustomerData(v :: values)
}
```

Comment: That works but gets cumbersome if I have a couple of different methods in the same type to be parameterized. At any rate its a possibility.